ECONNREFUSED - NextJs Keycloak Auth in Docker not working
I have a NextJs Application and want to integrate Authentication with Keycloak. The Application runs in Docker Containers. I created an API Route that should handle the Login with Keycloak. The page itself works. The Login Button from Keycloak is displayed but when i click on this Button an Error is displayed that the connection to the Keycloak URL was refused. I cant figure out what the Problem is.
I use NextJs 14 and Keycloak 25.0.1
This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  nextjs:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: sh -c "npm run dev"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    command: ["mysqld", "--init-file=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"]
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - keycloak-data:/opt/keycloak/data
      - ./keycloak-config:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    command: ["start-dev", "--import-realm"]

volumes:
  mysql-data:
  keycloak-data:

This is my pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts API Route:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak"

export const authOptions = {
  debug: true,
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER || "",
    //   profile(profile) {
    //     return {
    //       id: profile.sub,
    //       name: profile.name ?? profile.preferred_username,
    //       email: profile.email,
    //     }
    //   },
    }),
  ],
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)

…and these are the values in my .env:
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=nextjs_client
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET=abcdefghijklmnopqrs
KEYCLOAK_ISSUER=http://localhost:8080/realms/nextjs

And finally this is the error in my container log that occurs when i click the keycloak-signin-button:
nextjs-1    | https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 {
nextjs-1    |   error: {
nextjs-1    |     message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080',
nextjs-1    |     stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080\n' +
nextjs-1    |       '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16)\n' +
nextjs-1    |       '    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)',
nextjs-1    |     name: 'Error'
nextjs-1    |   },
nextjs-1    |   providerId: 'keycloak',
nextjs-1    |   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080'
nextjs-1    | }

I…

…tried replacing localhost with keycloak in my .env File for the KEYCLOAK_ISSUER to reference to the container but when i then clicked on Sign in with Keycloak i was redirected to the URL http://keycloak:8080/… which of course did not work in the Browser.
…tried setting the Node Option: --dns-result-order=ipv4first which i found from another post about this Problem. But it did not work
…tried searching for the Problem but didnt find any working solution


I had some issues with a NextJS and Keycloak application as well, but I managed to resolve them and I'll try to help you with some things I did. I'll provide the example using JavaScript, and you can convert it to TypeScript afterwards.

First, try commenting out the MySQL service from your application and deal only with NextJS and Keycloak. When that works, proceed to the next steps. That's how I managed to solve my issue.

The error seems to be in some configuration of NextAuth. A very common mistake, which I was making and you also made, was using localhost:8080 when the correct one is to use keycloak:8080, since you are using Docker to communicate. If you open an application and try to access from one container to another, this is the correct way to do it. If it is from something outside Docker to an exposed port, you can access using localhost.

About your .env file. I preferred to configure everything in the NextJS .env.local file. That way, it’s not so confusing with several .env files. Remember that you need to create a Realm and a Client to copy the key and then save it in your .env file. So correct your Issuer to http://keycloak:8080/realms/{realm_name}.

Add the environment variables in keycloak; replace the latest version with one you want, it can be 25.


Here is a complete example of my docker-compose:

    version: "3.8"
    
    services:
      nextjs:
        build:
          context: ../../
          dockerfile: docker/development/Dockerfile
        image: nextjs
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
          - "../../:/app/"
          - /app/node_modules/
          - /app/.next/
        environment:
          - HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0
          - NODE_ENV=development
    
      keycloak:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        environment:
          - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
          - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
        volumes:
          - keycloak_data:/opt/keycloak/data
        command: ["start-dev"]
    
    volumes:
      keycloak_data:


After that, configure your nextauth file again

    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
    import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";
    
    export const authOptions = {
      secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
      providers: [
        KeycloakProvider({
          clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
          issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
        }),
      ],
    };
    
    export default NextAuth(authOptions);


When it works, it would be good to add callbacks to this file. Start by using the basics from the NextAuth documentation and then improve it.
Take a look at my .env too.


    KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID={client name created after a realm)
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET={secret key generated after realm configuration}
    KEYCLOAK_ISSUER=http://keycloak:8080/realms/{your_realm}
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET={secret random key}


How to generate a random secret key:


    node -e "console.log(require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex'))"


I hope this is enough to solve your problem as it was in my case.
